# I turned my PDF import menu in photoshop off, how do I turn it ON?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, import, template

A while ago I turned that automatic import menu for pdfs off, because it was quite annoying and I was opening lots of pdfs.

Now I'm trying to open an A4 template, saved from Silhouette studio, with registration marks for a cutting machine into Photoshop, but it opens automatically in the wrong size. I need to open the original A4. I cannot add a layer below the design and just fill it with white (in photoshop). I can also not change the image size and 'just make it A4' because those registration marks are very specific, it needs to be correct in MM, otherwise the cuttingmachine doesn't work.

How can I turn that PDF import box on?
The preview shows A4, so the file from Silhouette studio is saved correctly.

Comment: Hi. How did you swtich off the PDF import dialog?  As far as I know that isn't usually possible. Did you install a script or something?